# How to string concatenate two bindings in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, string, gridview, binding

I would like to string concatenate two bindings into one string. How can I do this? I tried the below, but only LastName shows up when I run the application.

```
<asp:Label ID="txtFacultyName" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("FirstName") + Bind("LastName") %>'/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of options.

1. Create a combined property in your code behind/model:

   ```
   // cs
   public string FullName 
   {
       get { return $"{FirstName} {LastName}"; }   
   }

   // aspx
   <asp:Label ID="txtFacultyName" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("FullName") %>'/>
   ```
2. Use `Eval`.  Eval will allow one-way binding which is fine for displaying in an `asp:Label`

   ```cs
   <asp:Label ID="txtFacultyName" 
              runat="server" 
              Text='<%# string.Format("{0} {1}", Eval("FirstName"), Eval("LastName")) %>'/>
   ```